# SQLite WHERE clause issue on INTEGER column

Tags: android, sqlite, integer, where-clause

my Android application uses several tables like the following :

```
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "releve";
[...]
public static final String DH_ECRITURE_BASE = "dhEcritureBase";

private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" +
            ID_RELEVE         + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            ID_COMPTEUR    + " INTEGER, " +
            ID_MATERIEL    + " INTEGER, " +
            NATURE       + " TEXT, " +
            DH_RELEVE    + " INTEGER, " + 
            VALEUR_RELEVE       + " TEXT, " +
            COMMENTAIRE       + " TEXT, " +
            DH_ECRITURE_BASE    + " INTEGER" +
            ");";
```

When I request with a WHERE on the last column, which contains large values, nothing happens.
For example :

```
String query = "DELETE FROM releve WHERE dhEcritureBase='1760323320'";
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
```

does not work.

Of course, there is a record with the right value in dhEcritureBase. A WHERE on other numeric columns works well.

Is there a known issue with SQLite and INTEGER columns containing large values?

Comment: The max integer value allowed is (2^63)-1=9223372036854775807. Are the values that you have larger?

Comment: No, it's basically getTime() transformed into seconds, it's big but it doesn't exceed 8 bytes in theory.
If I duplicate my record and change the value of dhEcritureBase with '123' for example, well it works! But with '1760323320' or similar, no :(

Comment: in which environment did u test the query? I've had an issue earlier with requesting stuff from my db as well and the problem was that Android Studio wasn't up to date and didn't notice issues in my project that were needed for targeting api  31. I'd recommand isolating the db from your project and testing the query directly on your database. Also u might wanna have an index on DH_ECRITURE_BASE column

Comment: The code is running on smartphone, I develop with Android Studio and I target API 31. I will get the database and see how it behaves on another environment...

Comment: Thanks to DennisVA that was a good idea to isolate the database.
Using an external DBMS I understood.
The value read (and used in the where clause) by the application was not the same as the one actually written. Because of a cursor.getInt instead of a cursor.getLong. This explains why it worked correctly for all values coded at 4 bytes or less.